# How do I build a WordPress Profile/Author Header?

Tags: theme-development

I am working on a WordPress theme offline in localhost It's a blog theme: http://preview.themeforest.net/item/paperback-magazine-wordpress-theme/full_screen_preview/13511026 . I need to create a profile header in such a way that these writers would be able to put in their bio, a background picture, profile picture and links to their social networks. Something similar to this:

http://thoughtcatalog.com/rania-naim/

I am just starting out theme development and don't know my way around this. Will be grateful for any help. Thanks

Comment: Show us your code attempts?

Comment: I have not really started out, but I know how to find my way if I am being shown a way

Answer (score 0):

A quick way to find your way is by installing the [ACF](https://br.wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) plugin with these rules:

[image]

And create **author.php** file with this code:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <?php // get the background_picture ?>
    <?php $background_picture = get_field( 'background_picture', 'user_'.get_the_ID() ); ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $background_picture['url'] ?>" alt="">

    <?php // get the profile_picture ?>
    <?php $profile_picture = get_field( 'profile_picture', 'user_'.get_the_ID() ); ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $profile_picture['url'] ?>" alt="">

    <?php // get the bio ?>
    <?php echo get_the_author_meta( 'description' ) ?>

<?php endwhile ?>
```

Comment: Thanks so much. You've made coding so much easier. I surely can find my way from here.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a plugin like [Ultimate Member](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ultimate-member/) to get this done. Out-of-the-box it supports everything you ask for (profile photo, cover photo, bio, social media links, published articles) and you can customize this information using a simple drag-and-drop editor.

If you want to achieve a specific design, you may need to fiddle with the code a little bit, but if you're looking for an easy, "no-programming needed" solution, this would be your best bet.

There are other similar plugins, but IMO this is a simple and free solution for what you're looking for. I use the plugin on my site and haven't had any issues so far.